# Partial integration of $\int_0^L \overline{f(x)}(-f''(x))dx$

Tags: integration

I want to show that $\int_0^L \overline{f(x)} (-f''(x))dx$ is nonnegative with $f'(0)=0,f'(L)=0$. I tried with partial integration and got

\begin{align}
\int_0^L \overline{f(x)} (-f''(x))dx &= [\overline{f(x)}(-f'(x)]_0^L - \int_0^L \overline{f'(x)}(-f''(x))dx \\
&= \int_0^L \overline{f'(x)}f''(x)dx \\
&= [\overline{f'(x)}f'(x)]_0^L - \int_0^L \overline{f''(x)}f''(x)dx \\
&= -\int_0^L \overline{f''(x)}f''(x)dx
\end{align}

But I really dont see that the integral is nonnegative. Thank you in advance.

NOTE: there should be a bar over f(x) but it's quite small.

Comment: Use \overline not \bar for variable-length bar over a term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made errors in your integration by parts. It should read
$$\int_0^L\overline{f(x)}(-f''(x))dx=\overline{f(x)}(-f'(x))\Big|_{x=0}^L-\int_0^L\overline{f'(x)}(-f'(x))dx=\int_0^L|f'(x)|^2dx,$$
which certainly is non-negative.